# DBeaver - disable source query window

Tags: user-interface, dbeaver

I have a question about DBeaver (version 24.0.0) that boggles me:
Whenever I run a query that runs into an error, I get a reminder window of the query that was executed, which I do not need - how can I disable this?

Illustrated, I want this (purposefully messed up) query result view:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1OZM.png)

..to look similarly to a successful one, so only including the "results", in case of an error, the error message of course:
[successful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrLC3.png)

Thank you in advance for your help!

Note: I know the input SQL window can be hidden with that little arrow in the middle, but I don't want to do that for every execution, it would be best if it wouldn't show up at all.